# How to use c++ in html

Tags: html, c++

I have tried so hard but I can't get C++ to work in my HTML. I need it.

```
<script type="application/cpp">
  print('Hello world')
</script>
```

I know it will probably need a lib.

Comment: c++ in html...? Do you have a source that says this is possible? This is the first I hear of this. Are you expecting there to be a JIT compiler made in javascript? Most browsers only support html, css, and javascript.

Comment: Ohhh well can i embed c++ in a flv then or tis their some sort of compiler

Comment: Are you trying to display some c++ code in the webpage, or are you trying to get the browser to run your c++ code?

Comment: kind of bolth i guess

Comment: By flv do you mean flash video?

Comment: Yes i mean flash

Comment: It can't be both. You're either trying to display example code and format it nicely, or expecting the web browser to run your code like a program.

Comment: Flash player runs actionscript byte code, not c++ code. Are you sure you need c++ in specific? Why do you think you need c++ code in html?

Comment: what about just runing it

Comment: becuse i have a app already coded in c++

Comment: I mean you can run lua in the browser

Comment: Well... the thing is c++ compilers generally compile to native executables. What you're looking for is a compiler that can produce something a web browser can run. Why not just create a download link to your calculator on the school site?

Comment: so i guess is it posible to embed c++ in lua

Comment: if not then @ArticScript is the one who said the only thing that seems to work posibly

Comment: why did you downvote me?

Comment: oh well i found my answer that artic gave gonna go code cya sometime maybe

Comment: I researched javscript c++ interpreter for you and found something.

Comment: I dont know why the original question was downvoted, linked to a question which is totally different and closed by @Roko C. Buljan, but even in 2020 there was WebAssembly (https://webassembly.org/), which modern browsers support. WebAssembly is a binary instruction format which modern browsers can run, and with emcc compiler you can compile C/C++ programs and run the webassembly output in the browser (with certain limitations, of course)

Check out the already completed projects here: https://madewithwebassembly.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="application/cpp">
     print('Hello world')   
    </script>
```

Browsers support running HTML, CSS, and Javascript. You can't inject c++ code into a web page in this manner. You will have to find a solution by means of browser plugin or an interpreter or compiler written in Javascript.

An example interpreter written in Javascript is [JSCPP](https://github.com/felixhao28/JSCPP) you can use the "with a modern browser" option to run a c++ program on a webpage.